# Trouble displaying javax.swing components, specifically JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, clock

I'm creating a kind of to-do-list application. On one side, you have the to-do-list application with boxes where you can add your tasks, and on the other side you have a digital clock. The to-do-list works and displays perfectly. The clock, on the other hand, doesn't display at all. When I instantiate a Clock object by itself in a test program, it runs perfectly, but when I try to instantiate it inside the JFrame with the to-do-list, it simply doesn't display. I've checked my driver and I have instantiations and declarations for my clock object. What am I doing wrong?

ClockPanel object:

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;
 import javax.swing.Timer;

 public class ClockPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    private Timer timer;
    private javax.swing.JLabel clockLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    public ClockPanel() {
     super();

     clockLabel.setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
     clockLabel.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 100));
     clockLabel.setOpaque(true);
     clockLabel.setBackground(Color.black);
     clockLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

     timer = new Timer(500, this);
     timer.setRepeats(true);
     timer.start();

     clockLabel.setVisible(true);

     initComponents();
  }
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     if(e.getSource().equals(timer))
        clockLabel.setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
  private void initComponents() {

     javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
     this.setLayout(layout);
     layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
     layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
  }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
 }
```

The Clock object itself:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Clock extends JLabel implements ActionListener{
  private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
  private Timer timer;
  public Clock(){
     super();

     setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
     setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 100));
     setOpaque(true);
     setBackground(Color.black);
     setForeground(Color.white);

     timer = new Timer(500, this);
     timer.setRepeats(true);
     timer.start();

     setVisible(true);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     if(e.getSource().equals(timer))
        setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
  }
 }
```

Comment: where do you add your clockpanel to your jframe?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Also, why do both classes have a `Timer`?

Comment: BTW - 1) `clockLabel` is a standard `JLabel`, as opposed to a `Clock` 2) `clockLabel` is never added to any container. 3) ..So the panel probably has a 0x0 size. 4) More when I see that SSCCE.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong" - u mean besides generating UIs? :) I'd suggest you take a simple code example and grow" it into your app

Answer (score 4):

`clockLabel` is never added to any group of the layout.   This SSCCE fixes that.

[image: ClockPanel]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.ParallelGroup;

public class ClockPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    private Timer timer;
    private JLabel clockLabel = new JLabel("Ha Ha");

    public ClockPanel() {
        super();

        clockLabel.setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
        clockLabel.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 100));
        clockLabel.setOpaque(true);
        clockLabel.setBackground(Color.black);
        clockLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        timer = new Timer(500, this);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();

        initComponents();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource().equals(timer))
            clockLabel.setText(sdf.format(
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
        ParallelGroup parallelGroupH = layout.createParallelGroup(
                GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                parallelGroupH
                .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                );
        ParallelGroup parallelGroupV = layout.createParallelGroup(
                GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                parallelGroupV
                .addGap(0, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                );
        parallelGroupH.addComponent(clockLabel);
        parallelGroupV.addComponent(clockLabel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ClockPanel());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Linda Lay: `clockLabel.setVisible(true);` or any other `setVisible()` calls to `JComponent` won't make them appear. You add them to Swing's component hierarchy (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#general)